# Connect via SSH to a Raspberry Pi while using a VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, putty, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to my local network via ethernet cable, I access it with putty through my laptop connected to the same network, at the local address 192.168.x.x port 22.

Now I would like to connect my Raspberry Pi to a VPN (in this case NordVPN) but obviously after having given the command `nordvpn connect` the connection with putty to the Raspberry Pi is lost, I think because the packets coming out of the Raspberry Pi at this point are forwarded to the servers of NordVPN and not to my computer.

So is there a way to properly connect to my Raspberry Pi in my network while a VPN is active on the Raspberry?

Answer (score 0):

The same question is asked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365285/how-to-allow-ssh-into-terminal-after-connecting-to-vpn-server-using-nordvpn-serv. The solution was to run there command to allow the ssh packets to bypass the vpn connection.

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 128
ip route add table 128 to y.y.y.y/y dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via z.z.z.z
```

Where x.x.x.x is your Server public IP, y.y.y.y/y should be the subnet of your Server public IP address, eth0 should be your Server public Ethernet interface, and z.z.z.z should be the default gateway.

Comment: sorry but I don't have much knowledge about it, my Server public IP should be the ip address of my rasperry so for example 192.168.1.12? how do i find the subnet of my public ip server and the default gateway?

Comment: The Server public IP is 192.168.1.12 in your case and the subnet is probably 192.168.1.1/24, this can be calculated using a subnet calculator found online. The default gateway is the ip address of you router and is probably 192.168.1.1.